# Where is the file upload path on a webserver?

Tags: file-upload, web

I'm currently testing file upload vulnerability. How should I identify the webserver's file upload path by analyzing or intercepting the POST traffic?

Comment: Are you asking how to figure out what the web server's upload endpoint (the "path" component of the URL) is, or where the file ends up on the server's file system, or something else? The first is trivial (it's the path of the POST request, visible in any proxy or just the dev tools), the second is impossible without either the server source code or finding a vuln in the server (and indeed, there's no guarantee the server stores the upload in its file system at all!)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP traffic using POST is not limited to file uploading. Some other sources do exist. It legitimately includes other HTML forms using HTTP POST method without file upload or web API endpoints. Also, arbitrary requests for any client that effectively uses an HTTP POST method.

If you do have application source code, a faster way would be to security audit the file upload part, directly looking for vulnerabilities. If you use a tool to intercept traffic, you should filter the HTTP requests to only the ones with the form upload URI path. However, the effective upload location on the server file system depends on the source code and potentially the server configuration.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using any intercepting proxy like Burp or Zap, it would show up there.

If you are testing using a browser, open developer tools, check the Network tab. Reload once before sending, and then send. You will know where the application is sending the POST traffic.